# Is there a way to open a user's vignette in a Shiny link?

Tags: r, shiny

I've got a package that has a shiny app included. I would like to include a link in the app to open the vignette. I'd prefer to have the link directly open the user's version of the vignette (ie...I'd rather not have to maintain a copy of the vignettes online somewhere). I'm not sure the package will ever go to CRAN, so I don't want to depend on a CRAN link either (and the shiny app will only ever be run locally). I've tried this is the ui code:

```
 vig_path <- system.file("doc", package="myPackage")      
 HTML(paste0("<a href=\"file:///", vig_path,"/Introduction.html\">Introduction</a>"))
```

When copy the link location and paste it in the browser (ie, from "Inspect" via Chrome dev tools), it opens (so, the path is correct). There is an error "Not allowed to load local resource:". So, am I just out of luck, or is there a trick to open local files that I'm missing?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but vignette on [pkgdown](http://pkgdown.r-lib.org/) site is compromise between a (a) local vignette and (b) a CRAN vignette.  By default, all the vignettes appear under the 'Articles' tab in the navbar.

Comment: Yeah, pkgdown is great. In this instance, I'd rather not have to maintain an online presence (it's an internal package). But, in general it's a super option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, most of the magic for showing vignettes in R happens in the `utils:::print.vignette` function. This function can get the URL for the help page using R's built-in help system. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to make it easy to extract this URL from the function itself. But we can cut out the guts and wrap it ourselves. For example

```
get_vignette_link <- function(...) {
  x <- vignette(...)
  if (nzchar(out <- x$PDF)) {
    ext <- tools::file_ext(out)
    port <- if (tolower(ext) == "html") 
      tools::startDynamicHelp(NA)
    else 0L
    if (port > 0L) {
      out <- sprintf("http://127.0.0.1:%d/library/%s/doc/%s", 
              port, basename(x$Dir), out)
      return(out)
    }
  }
  stop("no html help found")
}
```

And we can use it like

```
get_vignette_link("programming", package="dplyr")
```

and that should return the URL for that vignette. It takes the same parameters as the `?vignette` function does. You can then use that to create a link in your Shiny app. For example

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  htmlOutput("text")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
   output$text <- renderUI({
      a("dplyr programming vignette", 
          href=get_vignette_link("programming", package="dplyr"))
   })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Because you are going through R's HTML help server, you don't have to access the local file path so you shouldn't get permission errors.

Comment: Super, thanks! I learned you need to always "Install and Restart" the package build compared to  using devtools::load_all for the get_vignette_link to work